# Uppercase every characters outside the parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string includes parentheses inside:

> I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)

I want to transform it into:

> I WANT TO UPPERCASE THIS STRING (except this) AND (this)

What is the best way to do it in JavaScript? If I have to use regex, please explain clearly because I am not good at regex.

Best regards,

Comment: You can use JavaScript(string methods or bitwise operations) or CSS or regex. You really need to give us more specifics about what you're building and how you're building it. Code and what you've tried would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may be simpler to uppercase the lot then lowercase between parens

```
var str = "I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)";

str = str.toUpperCase().replace(/(\(.+?)\)/g, m => m.toLowerCase());
```

To preserve case:

```
var str = "I want to uppercase this string (eXcEpT ThIs) and (ThIS)";

str = str.toUpperCase().replace(/\((.+?\))/g, (m, c, o) => str.substr(o, m.length));

> I WANT TO UPPERCASE THIS STRING (eXcEpT ThIs) AND (ThIS)
```

Comment: Note that this only is useful if we are certain that in the original text everything between parens is always lower case only. *PS I didn't downvote.*

Comment: Thats certainly  true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex, and then replace with a callback

```js
var str = "I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)";
var res = str.replace(/[^()](?=([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)/g, t => t.toUpperCase());

console.log(res)
```

The regular expression does the following

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
-----------------------------------------
  [^()]                    any character except: '(', ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /g                       global
```

Without any regular expressions

```js
var str = "I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)";
var par = false;
var res = str.split('').map(function(c) {
  par = c == '(' ? true : c == ')' ? false : par;
  return par ? c : c.toUpperCase();
}).join('')

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The non regex answer has some nice flip-flopping ;). Maybe also par = c === "(" || (par && c !== ")")

Comment: @Jonasw - nice one, a little golfing is always fun -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bLyrLk5v/

Answer (score 1):

This might be simpler:

```js
var str = 'I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)';

var repl = str.replace(/[a-z]+(?![^()]*\))/g, m => m.toUpperCase())

console.log(repl);

//=> "I WANT TO UPPERCASE THIS STRING (except this) AND (this)"
```

This assumes `(` and `)` are balanced and unescaped in input.

Negative lookahead `(?![^()]*\))` asserts we match a string that is not followed by a `)` with no `(` or `)` in between.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is a better way, but a quick and dirty way to use not

```js
var x = 'I want to uppercase this string (except this) and (this)'.replace( /(^[^(]+)|(\)[^(]+)/g, function (a,b) { return (a || b).toUpperCase()})
console.log(x)
```